# Compare two strings and return the unmatched sub string

Tags: php

I need to get the unmatched characters or words (i.e substring) by comparing the two strings.

For Ex:

```
$str1 = 'one {text} three'; // {text} is a keyword to find the position where my substring output is located
$str2 = 'one two three';

//I need to return following output
$output = 'two';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this my replacing the `{text}` placeholders with a regular expression pattern. Then use `preg_match_all` on the second string to find the matching segments.

```
$str1 = 'one {text} three {text} five';
$str2 = 'one two three four five';

$pattern = str_replace('{text}', '([\w]+)', $str1);

preg_match_all("/{$pattern}/", $str2, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str1 = 'one {text} three';
$str2 = 'one two three';

$str11 = explode(' ', $str1);
$str22 = explode(' ' , $str2);

$result=array_diff($str22,$str11);

print_r($result);
```

This outputs 
Array ( [1] => two )

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I feel this is not right approach to do that, Other answer gives a some solution.